# Orbeon Forms - validation regex lookahead

Tags: regex, orbeon

I want to use regex validation formula on Text Field. Here is pure regex:

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){7})\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

When I test this expression in regex online tools (eg: https://regex101.com/) everything works fine.
But when I try to use this as validator in Orbeon like this:

```
matches(string(.), '^(?!(?:\D*\d){7})\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$')  or xxf:is-blank(string(.))
```

I get error 'Incorrect XPath expression'.

When I removed from regex lookahead part, I was able to use it.

```
matches(string(.), '^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$')  or xxf:is-blank(string(.))
```

Is Orbeon Forms supports regex lookahead?
Regex lookahead:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: At regex101, [it does not work fine](https://regex101.com/r/clyjaX/1). Because I chose `RE2` (Go) regex engine that does not support lookarounds. You are using XMLSchema regex flavor that does not allow lookarounds either.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will look for workaround that works on Go regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write the expression without lookahead. It matches strings with no more than 6 digits.

Use

```
^(\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?|\d{5}(\.\d)?|\d{6})$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/CmOX8Z/1)

EXPLANATION

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 4 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{5}                    digits (0-9) (5 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3 (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of \3 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \3)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{6}                    digits (0-9) (6 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. This regex works very well.